# Styling reusable components in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, styling

I made a reusable component `Button.js` and I'm importing it on two different screens. The button looks the same, but on the first screen I need it to be `position: 'absolute'` and on the second one `position: 'relative'` (the default).

How do I add the position to be absolute on the first screen? I tried to add the styling on `FirstPage.js` but it does not work. How do I overwrite the style that is defined in `Button.js`?

`Button.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ position, onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle, {'position': position}}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{children}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  position: 'relative',
}

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#F44336',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    zIndex: 2,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  }
};

export { Button };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass props, something like this (Button.js) (edited according to posted code):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ position, onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
  const style = {...buttonStyle, position };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={style}>
        <Text style={textStyle}>{children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  position: 'relative',
}

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#F44336',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    zIndex: 2,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  }
};

export { Button };
```

Your button of course looks different, this is just an outline of what you could do (basically just using props).

Comment: The position works, but the other styles disappeared.
Now I have in `Button.js`:  `style={buttonStyle, {'position': position}}` and
`buttonStyle: {width: 100, backgroundColor: '#FFF',}`
If I write `style={{'position': position}, buttonStyle}` the position disappears but the styling is there

Comment: Try `style={...buttonStyle, ...{ 'position': position }}`.

Comment: It gives me unexpected token :(

Comment: Could you post content of your `Button.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

This is REUSABLE Button as touchableOpacity.

```
export const NormalThemeButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[{ ...props.style, ...styles.normalThemeBtn }]}
            style={[{ alignItems: props.align }, styles.anchor]}
            onPress={props.onPress} >
            <CustomText text={props.text} l bold style={{
                textAlign: 'center',
                color: theme['blackColor']
            }} />
             {props.children}
        </TouchableOpacity >
    );
};
```

This is where this RESUABLE Button is been used.

```
   style={{ ...styles.openArrivedButton }}
   text={Lng.instance.translate('useWaze')}
   onPress={() => { Waze() }}/>
```

Hope You find it helpful.